# Sox stopped working

Tags: sox

I'm using sox in this setup: `sudo timeout 20 rtl_fm -f 115.5M -s 60k -g 45 -p 55 -E wav -E deemp -F 9 - | sox -t wav - test.wav rate 11025`, it worked for quite a while but since last week it stopped working and prints this error message:

```
sox FAIL formats: can't open input  `-': WAVE: RIFF header not found
```

The error message is not really useful though because I specifies the header already with `-t wav`...What do I need to change to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "specify the header" with `-t wav`, you tell sox that it should expect a file in WAV format on `stdin`. So `sox` dutifully starts to parse `stdin`, and expects a `RIFF` header as part of the WAV format, but doesn't get it.

So it's not "sox stopped working", it's `rtl_fm` which is for some reason not producing a valid WAV format. Checking the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rtl_fm.1.html), at least for the version of `rtl_fm` on the man page, the file type is given by `-t wav`, and not by `-E wav`. So check the options to `rtl_fm`.

Did you introduce a typo last week in the command line?

Comment: I found the problem. It was not that rtl_fm send the wrong header but that it sent no header at all because there was no data. After a quick reboot it worked again as usual ;D. Thx for the quick help!

Comment: The state of rtl_fm is truly wonky: The manpage I have states that the 't' flag is used for 'squelch_delay' yet in the examples shown on the same page it is used to specify output type. At this point one can't be sure what's happening without reading the source code or experimenting.